# Databound Triangle Creation?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, shapes

I've got a requirement to create several shapes based on a supplied size (all of them have the same height/width) and have their sizes be databound to that supplied property on the datacontext.

Most of the shapes are easy: Circle (ellipse with height/width bound), square (rectangle with height/width bound), diamond (same as square, then use a RotateTransform), + (two lines), X (two lines).

But I'm trying to figure out how to do it for a triangle and I can't figure it out. It needs to be a filled object, so I can't just do it with three lines.

But all of the ways i've seen to do it (w/ a `Path` or a `Polygon`) end up taking `Point` objects (`StartPoint`, `EndPoint`, etc). And you can't bind to the `X` or `Y` values of the `Point` object.

Am I missing something? Or do I need to write my own custom shape or something?

Edit: To add a little bit of clarity... the type of triangle I'm creating doesn't really matter. It can be equilateral or isosceles. I was targeting an isosceles, so that it would have a base with the databound width and the top "tip" of the triangle will be at the mid-point of the databound width and at Y=0. That was just an optimization for simplicity's sake

Comment: You're right, a rectangle cannot be discribed just by its size. What kind of rectangles are you dealing with? Are they not isosceles ones?

Comment: @Dmitry - I assume you meant triangle there, not rectangle. I added some additional information for clarification purposes of what kind of triangle I'm going for.

Comment: Well, if your triangles are isosceles  (which is enought) they can easily be described by a rectangle, which they fit in. Another words knowing the rectangle which a triangle fits in and the fact that the triangle is isosceles I can always say exactly what the triangle is.:) So, you can stick to your sizes and write a simple behavior which will calculate your Xs and Ys.

Comment: Well, right. But my problem is finding a WPF construct that can databind the isosceles triangle based on a given height/width. @Erno's answer below may be the easiest way, but means I need to modify my viewmodel, which I'm trying to avoid doing (technically I don't own it).

Comment: Tim, aren't behaviors the machanism for doing that? You'll need to create a path and attach a behavior, so it'll look as follows: 
<Path Width="100" Height="100" Stroke="Green" StrokeThickness="2" PathBehavior.ShapeType="Isosceles" /> Looks slick, the complexity ih hidden inside your PathBehavior.ShapeType implementation.

Comment: @Dmitry - that's a good call. I hadn't thought of going that route. Going to have to go explore that. You might want to post that as an answer rather than a comment to make sure other people see it.

Comment: Tim, I'll craft the bahavior for you tomorrow and then post it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public enum ShapeType
    {
        Rectangle,
        Isosceles,
        Ellipse,
        Dice,
        Hexagon
    }

    public class PathControl
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ShapeTypeProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ShapeType",
            typeof(ShapeType?),
            typeof(DependencyObject),
            new PropertyMetadata(null, 
                new PropertyChangedCallback((sender, args) => 
                { 
                    Path path = sender as Path;
                    ShapeType? shapeType = (ShapeType?)args.NewValue;

                    //todo: use a WeakEvent
                    path.SizeChanged += 
                        (pathSender, pathArgs) => 
                        {
                            PathControl.InvalidatePath((Path)sender, shapeType);
                        };

                })));


        private static void InvalidatePath(Path path, ShapeType? shapeType)
        {
            if (path != null
                && shapeType.HasValue)
            {
                string source = null;

                double netWidth = path.Width - 2 * path.StrokeThickness,
                       netHeight = path.Height - 2 * path.StrokeThickness;

                if (shapeType == ShapeType.Rectangle)
                {
                    source = string.Format("M0,0 h{0} v{1} h-{0} z",
                        new object[2]
                        {
                            netWidth,
                            netHeight
                        });
                }
                else if (shapeType == ShapeType.Isosceles)
                {
                    source = string.Format("M0,{1} l{0},-{1} {0},{1} z",
                        new object[2]
                        {
                            netWidth / 2,
                            netHeight
                        });
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new NotImplementedException(shapeType.ToString());
                }

                path.Data = Geometry.Parse(source);
            }
        }

        public static void SetShapeType(DependencyObject o, ShapeType e)
        {
            o.SetValue(PathControl.ShapeTypeProperty, e);
        }

        public static ShapeType? GetShapeType(DependencyObject o)
        {
            return (ShapeType)o.GetValue(PathControl.ShapeTypeProperty);
        }
    }
}
```

The XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1">
    <Grid>
        <Path Width="100" Height="100" Stroke="Green" StrokeThickness="2" Fill="Yellow"
              local:PathControl.ShapeType="Isosceles">
            <Path.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="90"></RotateTransform>
            </Path.RenderTransform>
        </Path>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: I wish I could give you a +2 actually. I never even thought about the fact that I could construct my Geometry as a string like that. This was a very creative solution, so I'm going to mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Binding to the Points is the best/only way. The X and X properties of a Point cannot be bound to because they do not raise the PropertyChanged event. The Point is a structure and structures should be read-only.

The PointCollection class raises the correct events so you can bind to it. This allows you to manipulate the triangles by modifying the collection of point by replacing the points. Do not change the point but replace them so the proper events will be raised.

Comment: I was wondering if that was the route I would need to go. Unfortunately I don't "own" the viewmodel, so I only have the height/width properties to bind to. I suppose I may need to look into whether I can take ownership of that class and add some new properties to bind to.

Comment: You would first have to find out whether or not there are properties you can bind to or other change events that will allow you to update the View/ViewModel.